# How can i make like this structure?

Tags: images, videos, slideshow

Sorry, i'm newbie user Wordpress.

Want a accordion list like this:

```
News
News 1
News 2
News 3
```

And when click a accordion item, get image/video slider.

How can i make like this? Thank you

Sample img:
[image]

Comment: I can't see any accordion in any page of your example. There are only slideshows.

Comment: @user29296 Edited my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean when you click on each (or any) News item, you have the scroll list of video/image + the slider OR your accordion replaces the scroll list in your capture ?

Anyhow, i think this is more a javascript question than a Wordpress one.

You could use [jquery UI Accordion](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/) ,

or an accordion plugin,

or build a simple one like this

```
<ul id="accordion">
    <li>
        <h2>title1</h2>
        <div class="accordionitem">content 1 with slideshow (and scroller ?)</div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h2>title2</h2>
        <div class="accordionitem">content 2 with slideshow (and scroller ?)</div>
    </li>
    ...
</ul>
<script type="text/javascript">
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j("document").ready(function(){
    $j("#accordion div").slideUp("normal");
    $j("#accordion h2").each(function( index ) {
        $j(this).click(function(){
            $j("#accordion div").slideUp("normal");
            $j(this).parent().find('.accordionitem').slideDown("normal");
        });
    })
});

</script>
```